# how to make the data that we input appear in table in phpmyadmin (related to yii2)

Tags: php, web, yii2

I'm a newbie in yii2.

I have generated this code in gii using form generator

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Publikasi */
/* @var $form ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="publikasi">

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>


        <?= $form->field($model, 'NIP') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'Tanggal') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'StatusPenulis') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'JudulPenelitian') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'BidangKajian') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'NamaJurnal') ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'StatusJurnal') ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton(Yii::t('app', 'Submit'), ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
        </div>


    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div><!-- publikasi -->
```

when I run this code, the result come to the same page. my question is how can I see the data that i input to that form? I mean how to make the data appears in phpmyadmin's table?

[image]

Comment: "*..my question is how can I see the data that i input to that form?*" So, Where You Want To See Data.

Comment: yes you're right Nana. do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Actually, Where you want to see data? @ria

Answer (score 0):

`yii\base\View` has a special property called `params`.

For example it's used for building breadcrumbs in default generated CRUD code templates with Gii.

You can set it like this before rendering:

```
use Yii;

Yii::$app->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
```

Inside a controller you can set it like this:

```
$this->view->params['customParam'] = 'customValue';
Then it will be available in views (including main layout):

/* @var $this yii\web\View */

echo $this->params['customParam'];
You can also find it in official guide.
```

Comment: still dont understand :( can you tell me detailly? i mean step by step. hehe